# How to place markers around a string in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

Heyo. I've been trying to make a code that looks for a name in a string and simply marks it.

For example, if a name was given "Jerry Smith" and a passage or sentence was given "I saw Jerry Smith smell some trees.".

It would return "I saw [NAME]Jerry Smith[/NAME] smell some trees.

I thought it would be possible to do this just with the following:

```
public void markNames(String name, String text)
    {
        String replacementStr = "[NAME]" + name + "[/NAME]";
        String replacedStr = text.replaceAll(name, replacementStr);
        text = replacedStr;
    }
```

But that isn't doing anything on my end. I'm sure I need a more complex regex but I'm honestly not sure what to put in. I thought it would be simple enough to just find the name.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `textBlock.replaceAll`: Where is `textBlock` from?

Comment: use replace not replaceAll

Comment: @Tacocat opps sorry. should be text. I switched it and it still isnt working.

Comment: @ScaryWombat that doesn't work either. I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these two lines:

```
String replacementStr = "[NAME]" + name + "[/NAME]";
String replacedStr = textBlock.replaceAll(name, replacementStr);
```

To this:

```
String replacementStr = "[NAME]$1[/NAME]";
String replacedStr = textBlock.replaceAll("("+name+")", replacementStr);
```

## Why this works

`replaceAll()` uses regexes. By adding the parenthesis around  `name`, it becomes a capture group. I refer to this capture group as `$1` in the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

in the method[markNames],where is the variable[textBlock] from?
so,i changed you method

```
    public String markNames(String name, String text) {
    String replacementStr = "[NAME]" + name + "[/NAME]";
    String replacedStr = text.replaceAll(name, replacementStr);
    return replacedStr;
}
```

then,i used juint test it

```
    @Test
public void test15(){
    System.out.println(markNames("Jerry Smith", "I saw Jerry Smith smell some trees."));
}
```

This code outputs`I saw [NAME]Jerry Smith[/NAME] smell some trees.`This is the result you want?
and I think you should use the symbol [%s] instead of +

```
String replacementStr = String.format("[NAME]%s[/NAME]", name);
```